# Storing and ordering by an array/list of integers in a Django model

Tags: django, arrays, sorting, model, integer

I have a vector of three numbers as a name for a model.
i.e. 12-1-120 12-1-139 12-1-9 etc.

I wanted to sort instances of the model in descending order, using Django to display 12-1-139, 12-1-120, 12-1-9.

Except it always acts like a string, hence displaying 12-1-9, 12-1-139, 12-1-120.

I've tried using the 'CommaSeparatedIntegerField' yet it's totally useless and still acts the same way.

The only way that I know of, that would technically work, is by having three separate "IntegerField"s and ordering it by the combination, which I think is too impractical.

Any pointers, or am I stuck with this impractical method?

I forgot to mention that I also needed to sometimes call this object using a string and I didn't want to constantly convert the string to an int so I did it the other way around and stored the bunch of ints into a string using somewhat of a calculated field.

Here's my basic code:

```
class MyModelName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    x = models.IntegerField(max_length=200)
    y = models.IntegerField(max_length=200)
    z = models.IntegerField(max_length=200)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = '-'.join([str(self.x), str(self.y), str(self.z)])
        super(MyModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-x","-y","-z"]
```

Comment: Why is it impractical to have three integer fields?

Comment: I just thought it would be a lot neater to store it into a single field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three integer fields is the way to go.

If you want to name your objects that way, you could always add a **unicode** function to your model...

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()
    z = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        """
            Return a human-readable representation of the object.
        """
        return '-'.join(self.x, self.y, self.z)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode

**get_or_create example:**

```
s = '12-1-9'
x, y, z = [int(c) for c in s.split('-')]
thing, created = Thing.objects.get_or_create(x=x, y=y, z=z)
```

**custom get or create method**

```
class ThingManager(models.Manager):

    def from_string(s):
        x, y, z = [int(c) for c in s.split('-')]
        obj, created = self.get_or_create(x=x, y=y, z=z)
        return obj, created


class Thing(models.Model):
    objects = ThingManager()
    # Snip


--


my_new_thing, created = Thing.objects.from_string('12-1-9')
```

Comment: What would I do if I want to get_or_create this Thing after given a string containing "$x-$y-$z" i.e. "12-1-9"

Is there a way to have a field which is an automatically calculated string combining the three integers?

Comment: Just split the string into integers before calling get_or_create. Have added example code above.

Comment: I use the get_or_create method a lot, so I think it would be tedious and slower to always do the splitting method like that.

Comment: OK, well you can package that code up into a custom manager method. I've added an example above. It's better to store data in the correct way and format before you store, than to store incorrectly and format every time you want to use it. Here are the docs for custom managers: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but the join returns an error because it expects a string rather than an int.

    return u'%d-%d-%d' % (self.x, self.y, self.z)

This shouldn't have the same problem, except it's still converted to a string therefore the order get's messed up in the admin.

Comment: Order by the integer fields in the admin app... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering.